# How do I access rootGetters from a different namespaced module in Vuex?

Tags: vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, vuex, vuex-modules, vuexfire

I have a Vuex module named 'forms'. I have a different (also namespaced) module named 'users'.

I'm using Vuexfire (for the first time, which I think is what's tripping me up). And have an action that works like this:

```
      const actions = {
      loadPendingHoursRequests: firestoreAction((context) => {
        context.bindFirestoreRef('pendingHoursRequests', db.collection('hours')
        .where('submittedToUID', '==', "iTd865JKWXRmhz2D2mtW7KIpL7a2"))
      }),
```

This works as expected and creates a real-time connection between Firestore and Vuex. The problem is I want "iTd865JKWXRmhz2D2mtW7KIpL7a2" to be a dynamic value drawn from the 'users' module.

I'm just completely lost. If I refactor like this:

```
  loadPendingHoursRequests ({ dispatch, commit, getters, rootGetters }) {
    let uid = rootGetters['users/currentUserUID'];
    console.log(uid)
    firestoreAction((context) => {
      context.bindFirestoreRef('pendingHoursRequests', db.collection('hours').where('submittedToUID', '==', uid))
    })
  }
```

The console.log above returns 'undefined'. And even if I remove the `.where('submittedToUID', '==', uid)`, the firestoreAction doesn't work anyway.

Thanks in advance. I'd love to know what I'm not understanding here.

Comment: `console.log(rootGetters)`, what do you see?

Comment: For option 1 (above) `console.log(rootGetters)` returns "ReferenceError: rootGetters is not defined", which is probably to be expected.

Option 2 returns an object with all my getters listed.

Comment: Sorry to spam my own question. I think I'm messing something up with asynchronous code. `rootGetters['users/currentUserUID']` (above) returns undefined... But there is a user/currentUserUID according to Vuex dev tools. Idk.

Comment: Option 2, you see getters but not the namespaced getter I guess there's a module configuration problem

Comment: I tried to simplify things down to this (ignoring vuexfire for now).
`  loadPendingHoursRequests ({ dispatch, commit, getters, rootGetters }) {
    let uid = rootGetters['users/currentUser'];
    console.log(uid)
  }`

With interesting results. First console log returns: `{__ob__: observer}.`

But if I leave the page and come back I get the object I was looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Untested (I don't use VuexFire) but assuming the `bindFirestoreRef` needs the `context` object, you can access `rootGetters` as a property of it as well.  Putting the two snippets together ilke this:

```js
const actions = {
  loadPendingHoursRequests: firestoreAction((context) => {
    const uid = context.rootGetters['users/currentUserUID'];
    context.bindFirestoreRef('pendingHoursRequests', db.collection('hours')
      .where('submittedToUID', '==', uid))
  })
}
```

Comment: Yeah I tried this and it's saying uid is undefined. If I leave the page and come back (ie destroy and mount again) then the UID shows up and everything works. Somehow this function must be running before the "users/currentUserUID" has ran.

Comment: Sounds like a race condition resulting from calling this action too soon.  How/when does the getter get populated?